# "Method Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::pixelate does not exist."

Tags: laravel, pixelate

Here is my code:

```
   $avatar->pixelate(12);
```

It should pixelate the picture but it shows me this:

> "Method Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::pixelate does not exist."

Comment: the `$avatar` is as the error says, an [`UploadFile` class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.php). It dont have `pixelate` method. are you perhaps missing [Intervention's `pixelate`](http://image.intervention.io/api/pixelate)? do post us your dependencies stated on `composer.json`. and how did you load the image into Intervention - using `Image::make` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

This method does not exist in the [UploadedFile class](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.html). However, it is available in the very popular [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/api/pixelate) library.

Comment: And I am using intervention image

Comment: You need to call the method on an instance of Intervention Image. Not UploadedFile.

Answer (score 0):

It means `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` class does not have `pixelate` method. You can check laravel API to which class have which methods..

And as you can see [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.html) there is no method called `pixelate`